# android action bar style (splitted style and menu item pressed)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-styles

I set the background of my action bar, but in split mode the background does not work.

I see that I must set this :

```
<item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/some_drowable</item>
```

but it does not work in Api level 11

Is there any other way to do this ?

I have another question about action bar style, I want to change action bar icon color when it is pressed (not background area, but replace the icon). How can I do this ?

Comment: check values,values-11,values-14 folder same style appllied?

Comment: thank you , I can set backgroundsplit only for api 14 now, and works!
User using app with api<14 view different background, this is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The first, I don't know how to do that. But the second, I can help you with. It's not that difficult at all.

Basically, the action bar is just a bar with any menu options that you otherwise would have set under the menu button.

As such, it is created on the start of your application with a call to

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    ...
}
```

And any selected options will cause

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    ...
}
```

to be called, with the menu item that the user selected.

However, there is a third method that relates to the options menu, which is the one you want to use to update the action. It is called `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` ([link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29)). In this method, it is allowed to alter the menu that is created with `onCreateOptionsMenu(...)`.

So, with this knowledge, you can keep a (global) state for a specific item in `onOptionsItemSelected(...)` by checking which action was tapped in the action bar by calling `item.getItemId()`.

Now, you will have the knowledge of which action was tapped on the action bar, and the state you want it to be in.

But wait, the action bar was already created when the application launched. So how do you cause the it to be re-created? Very simple actually. You merely need a call to `invalidateOptionsMenu()` ([link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu%28%29)) to invalidate it. this causes Android to redraw the action bar, and causing the whole line of `onCreateOptionsMenu(...)` -> `onPrepareOptionsMenu(...)` to be called again.

So now you have everything you need:

1. Determine what action has been tapped by the user (`onOptionsItemSelected(...)`
2. What state you want to keep
3. How to redraw the action bar

When the action bar is being redrawn, you can change the icons for the items on the action bar so it will update to the state you want it to be.

Comment: thank you, but there isn't a simplest way ? I think something like onpressed="icon_pressed" in style xml

Comment: Nope, the action bar is static in the respect that when it has been created & drawn, you can't alter it until it gets a call to be redrawn.

Comment: I have different activity with different menu items, so I must write a lot of code for do it.

Comment: Well, you should already have 2 out of the mentioned 3 methods implemented if you have different menu items in different activities. I don't think it will take much to add the 3rd. ;)